# Cette phrase est-elle valide d'un point de vue typographique?

Tags: grammaire, typographie, ponctuation

Il est 13h30.
Oui ; Sommes-nous pressés ? Dois-tu aller quelque part ?

J'aimerais savoir si l'usage du point virgule dans cette phrase est valide.
Je vous remercie par avance pour vos réponses.

Answer (score 4):

Le point virgule [peut se définir comme suit](https://www.espacefrancais.com/lemploi-du-point-virgule/) :

> Le point-virgule est un signe de ponctuation marquant une pause un peu plus longue que la virgule.

Si l'on se réfère strictement à cette définition assez permissive, l'usage me semble **correct** dans ce contexte : la personne indique qu'en effet, il est 13h30, puis en l'absence de réponse (après une pause relativement longue, donc), pose des questions à son interlocuteur pour comprendre pourquoi il/elle insistait sur l'heure.

Cependant, cette utilisation ne me semble pas la plus naturelle. Si mon raisonnement précédent est le bon, alors un point (voire trois points de suspension) semblerait plus approprié car la pause est vraiment longue.

Enfin, si je peux apporter une petite correction, **le point-virgule est suivi d'une minuscule**, donc il faudrait écrire "Oui ; sommes-nous pressés ?"

Pour aller plus loin, voici [plusieurs](https://www.cordial.fr/grammaire/manuels/U_PTVIRG.htm) [pistes](http://www.la-ponctuation.com/point-virgule.html) [pour comprendre](https://bescherelle.ca/deux-points-point-virgule/) l'usage du point-virgule.

Answer (score 3):

**Non**. En effet, *oui* est une réponse à ce qui *précède*.

> Il est 13h30. Oui, effectivement. Sommes-nous pressés ? Dois-tu aller quelque part ?
>
> Il est 13h30. Euh, sommes-nous pressés ? Dois-tu aller quelque part ?